# Documentation of FacebookRestClientException

Tags: php, facebook

Using the Facebook REST API PHP client library, it seems wise to wrap calls in `try{}` thus:

```
require('facebook.php');
$fb = new Facebook($fbApiKey, $fbSecret);
try {
    $result = $fb->api_client->some_api_method(...);
} catch (FacebookRestClientException $e) {
    // now what?
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do with the exception, e.g. to find out what went wrong or to write a sensible message to the error log. Is there documentation for these exceptions somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

After examining the code and some example exceptions, I think `$e` is an object looking something like this:

```
(
  [message:protected] => An error message string
  [string:Exception:private] => Don't know
  [code:protected] => A numerical error code
  [file:protected] => File here the exception was thrown
  [line:protected] => Line where the exception was thrown
  [trace:Exception:private] => A PHP debug_backtrace() result
  [previous:Exception:private] => Don't know
)
```